# Calculated Column formula not working correctly on refresh

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column-formula

I have a List in SharePoint 2010 which contains a list of Vendors. The List has three columns: Vendor, Inactive, and SortVendor. SortVendor is a calculated column with the formula:

```
=IF(ISNULL(Inactive),Vendor,"zz"&Vendor)
```

ISBLANK(Inactive) does not produce correct results.

IF(Inactive=Retired, (Retired is the default state for this column) makes the 
calculated column Null if Inactive is empty, and will not work as such.

The purpose of this is to organize a drop-down list in InfoPath that organizes Vendors by activity then alphabetical order.

This method **was working previously**. Today I pulled a more updated list of Vendors from an access database, and remade the calculated column with the aforementioned formula. The very odd thing that happens is, the formula will work at the time which I put it in and save it, but if I refresh the page, or visit it later, the formula will default to the false value, putting "zz" in front of every Vendor name.

When viewing the list in Datasheet view, changing the formula to something else then back to the original formula will allow it to work again. After waiting for it to save to server, refreshing the page will make it malfunction again. Deleting the column and remaking it yields no results. As I mentioned, this was working previous to today when I created a new list.

Are there any known issues that cause calculated columns to malfunction on refresh, or any other such issues?